# Top and Bottom toolbars disappear after changing "Workspace Switcher Preferences" following 10.04 to 12.04 upgrade

Tags: gnome, compiz, workspaces

I updated from 10.04 to 12.04 yesterday. I used Gnome instead of Unity.

I also was configured to have a single row of 6 screens/desktops in the "Workspace Switcher Preferences". After the upgrade this was reset to be two rows of two screens/desktops.

When I set the preferences to again have a single row of 6 screens/desktops I initially see them show up on the bottom toolbar/panel.

The problems start when I try to switch to another screen from screen 0.
All decorations, toolbars, etc., disappear. I cannot force a manual switch between screens. All I see is the background.

If I do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd> to logout then log in again I get the toolbars/panels but they have been reset to 2 high and 2 wide instead of the single row of 6 that I set in the preferences.

What changed between 10.04 and 12.04 that would cause this and what do I need to do to get back the environment I wish to operate in?

(I am accustomed to having specific apps on specific screens/desktops so changing to a 2x2 model is not desirable.)

Thanks for any help you may provide on this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/134017/workspace-switching-not-working-with-12-04-and-gnome-classic-with-effects

Answer (score 1):

I found the following information on another thread at [Workspace switching not working with 12.04 and Gnome classic with effects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134017/workspace-switching-not-working-with-12-04-and-gnome-classic-with-effects)

The part that worked for me was to use ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager)

The answer at that link that I found useful was:
I initially had the same problem with workplace switching and only the background showing in Gnome classic, but the fix to Alt-Tab does not switch also fixed this - i.e. install compizconfig-settings-manager, and enable "application switcher".

Then if you wish to customize the arrangement of the workplaces from 2x2 to say 4x1, you can do that under Applications -> system tools -> preferences -> compizconfig settings manager -> general -> General options -> Desktop size -> horizontal virtual size = 4, vertical virtual size = 1.

I followed these instruction specifically to set 6 horizontal and 1 virtual and I achieved the desired results.
Perhaps this is a bug with the built-in "Workspace Switcher Preferences" where it is not configuring properly whereas ccsm does.